# Custom Keyboard or to create own keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-softkeyboard

i would like to increase the keyboard key size is that possible?

if i need to create my own custom keyboard , i want to increase the keyboard keys size.
Please provide me how can i go with implementing this...
any tutorials or code sample would be helpful .
Thanks for your time and views

Answer (score 3):

Standard keyboard appears as a window and you cann't change its size.

Custom keyboard is just a custom view with backgroundImage and about 30 buttons. I guess you should provide some datasource for this view (for different language supporting) and delegate like a `(void)keyboardDidPushLetter:(MyCustomKeyboard *)keyboard atIndex:(NSInteger)index;`. Just start implement it.